# Why can't my monk use the Frost Unarmed Attack +1?

Tags: dnd-4e, magic-items, unarmed-combat

I use the official D&D character creator and I currently have a monk who uses the monk unarmed strike attack.

I gave him the Primordial Adept theme and I want him to be able to constantly deal cold damage to take advantage of the Vulnerable 5 Cold that the Solkara's Grasp power gives him.

I found the *Frost unarmed attack +1* in the builder and it was perfect but when I went to buy it, it was red as if there is something wrong and I can't use it. Aren't monks proficient in unarmed attacks? Shouldn't I be able to use that item in place of my monk unarmed attack?

I thought it was an improved enchanted version of my monk unarmed attack so I'm really confused why I can't use it, and why it will only do a 1d4 while I'm wielding it when the monk unarmed strike does 1d8.

The monk is level 4, by the way, if that says anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunatly you cannot get enchanted unarmed attacks any more. I do not know why they still have them in the Character Builder, but if you select the normal Monk unarmed strike in your inventory it says:

> *UPDATE* The rules for monk unarmed strikes has changed since the playtest. Your unarmed strikes no longer can be enchanted, nor does it function as an implement. Talk with your DM about updating your character. A suggested resolution is to sell your enchanted unarmed strike and purchase a Ki Focus in its place.

I would suggest picking up a Frost Weapon of some sort, and just reflavor it. Sure you are holding a Frost Staff, but your actual attack is you kicking with your really cold feet (or something similar)

Comment: I haven't played a monk, and I'm not going to go through all the rules right now, but I have some familiarity with ki focuses from the Executioner class. Can a monk use the enhancement bonus and properties on their ki focus when attacking with an unarmed strike? Seems like that would make more sense than getting a frost weapon and pretending that it's not there.

Comment: @DCShannon they can use a ki focus with their unarmed strike, the problem is that there isn't a ki focus that makes all of your attacks cold, the best you can get is 2 turns and that requires you to spend your second wind

Comment: Ah, okay then. I'd suggest that the player talk to the DM about getting a custom ki focus that does cold damage.